# Creating a dataframe using contents of paragraphs in each webpage by web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a specific website using selenium and beautifulsoup. Idea is to get the link of each page and its corresponding paragraphs in a pandas dataframe.

So the resultant dataframe would be like

```
     Link                              Paras
https://www.<website>.com      contents of all <p> tags
   /specific_page.html
```

For this I am using the following code snippets:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\WebScrapp\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
link=[]
para = []
for e in elem:
    try:
        page = requests.get(e.get_attribute('href'))
        soup = bs(page.content,'lxml')
        paras = soup.find_all('p')
        for p in paras:
            if '<seacrh_strng>' in p.text:
                link.appned(str(e.get_attribute('href')))
                para.append(p.text)
    except:
        print('InvalidSchema: No connection adapters')
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(link,para),columns=['Link','Para'])
```

With the above, I am facing the below issues:

1. Most of the times (or for most the elements in `elem`) it is going to `except` block and thus printing `'InvalidSchema: No connection adapters'`.
2. The above technique is quite slow.

Eg. I have tried url like `https://www.cognizant.com` or `https://www.sas.com` or `https://www.bmc.com` and have got nothing in the dataframe. It is hard to believe that these websites are not using `<p>` as a tag!!

In fact I have tried out `paras = soup.find_all(re.compile('^h[1-6]$'))`,but no luck!

What I am missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest refactoring your code like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="D:\WebScrapp\chromedriver.exe"
)
driver.get("https://www.bmc.com")  # for testing purposes

elements = driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value="//a[@href]")

results = {"link": [], "ptag": []}

for element in elements:
    try:
        url = element.get_attribute("href")
        response = requests.request(method="get", url=url)
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
        for p_tag in parsed_html.find_all("p"):
            results["link"].append(url)
            results["ptag"].append(p_tag.text)
    except:
        continue
```

And then:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

print(df.sample(4))
# Output
                                                  link                                               ptag
55                               https://www.bmc.com/#  Gartner names BMC a Leader in the ITSM Magic Q...
138  https://www.bmc.com/it-solutions/bmc-helix-ope...           Winner of the 2021 AI Breakthrough Award
303       https://www.bmc.com/it-solutions/devops.html           Speak to a rep about your business needs
43                               https://www.bmc.com/#  Drive innovation through agility, customer cen...
```